# Activate on hover from typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project where user can either click on a map for a specifice region or click a radio button for a corresponding region. From a user experience perspective the demand has been made that the map also has the 'on hover' effect when selecting a region by radio button.

However, I can only think of using JQuery.  Is there an alternative i am not seeing here?

I am working in a Angular 14 environment with typescript 4.7.2.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Typescript code:

```
onChange(){
  this.activateOnHover(this.currentRegion.ID);
}
activateOnHover(selector: string): void {
  $("#"+selector).mouseover();
}
```

HTML:

```
(click)="onClick($event)"
```

Unfortunately I am limited in the amount of code I can post because of project restrictions.

**Update**

Id of the element i want to highlight:

```
id="Noord-Nederland" (click)="onClick($event)"
```

When implementing Wahab's suggestion:

```
  @ViewChild('#Noord-Nederland') input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

onChange(){
  this.activateHoverEffect(this.currentRegion.ID);
}
activateHoverEffect(selector: string): void {
  console.log(" 1")
  console.log(this.input);
  // Access the input object or DOM node
  console.log("2 ")
  console.dir(this.input.nativeElement);
  console.log("3")

  // Manipulate via Renderer2
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.input.nativeElement, 'background', '#d515a0');
}
```

After the 1, it logs undefined.

There are element that have the same ID, because the fact I am using SVG, however I cannot directly imagine his beeing the cause of the not being able to find the element.

Comment: What does jQuery do that you can't do in Angular/TypeScript/Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: You usually don't need JQuery inside of a framework like Angular or React.  There's other ways of handling it.  Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen In JQuery I can select element with $("Element_ID"). I do not know of a something similair with Typescript.

Comment: @DJBurb I posted what I could. This is the JQuery way I'd imagine it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are `mouseover` `mouseout` events or `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`

How you use is as follows:

```
<div (mouseover)='over()' (mouseout)='out()'>mouseover</div>


<div (mouseenter)='mEnter()' (mouseleave)='mLeave()'>mouse enter</div>
```

Then in you TS file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  .....
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'hovering';

  over(){
    console.log("Mouseover triggered");
  }

  out(){
    console.log("Mouseout triggered");
  }
}
```

**OPTION 2**

Apart from these, there is another option of using the attribute directives. `@HostListener`. Here is the sample code idea taken from the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

```
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.scss']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostListener('mouseenter') 
  onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight('yellow');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') 
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }

...

}
```

The docs Link: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

**UPDATE: Manipulating DOM with `ElementRef` & `Renderer2`**
Because directly manipulating the dom makes it tightly coupled and not recommended so `Renderer2` is the preferred way.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <input ngModel #username>
    <p>{{ username.value }}</p>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('username') input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // ElementRef: { nativeElement: <input> }
    console.log(this.input);

    // Access the input object or DOM node
    console.dir(this.input.nativeElement);

    // Manipulate via Renderer2
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.input.nativeElement, 'background', '#d515a0');
  }
}
```

For further reading : [Visit here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/element-refs-in-angular-templates)

Comment: Hello Wahab, thanks for your response.
I want to activate the hover effect, from the typescript. This looks to me your activating the typescript from the html with a on mouseover.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yeah like you will have to interact with certain element (lets say radio button in your case maybe). It is similar to what you have also mentioned in your code snippets too. 
There is one way if like you want to manpulate the then you can use `ElementRef` and `Renderer2`. See option 2 from the link I have shared plus I will update and add one of the snippets for dom manipulation

Comment: @Metaladdict check the updated answer.

Comment: I'll try and implement this. Thanks!

Comment: I posted an update with your code. It is now returns an undefined

Comment: you have given the id only not template variable with `#your_variable_name`
`<div #Noord-nederland click=...> </div>`.

Comment: I see now. This isn't a input element. It's  clickable SVG that prompts logic when clicked. It has CSS that reacts when hovered. I want the radio to activat said hover activaty on the SVG.

Comment: didn't get you?

Comment: I have an imagine. Built up with SVG. This SVG is clickable. When I click it, it must do some business logic. When I hover over said SVG element. It triggers the hover. This hover gives it the colour blue

I have some radio buttons. These call on the exact same logic. Only it doesn't do anything with SVG. 

There are no variable called. Only html and css is used. 

When the radio button is pressed. The hover mechanic needs to be trigger as well.

Comment: So just use host listener and trigger in when you hover over the svg element. And for radio button on change trigger the function you have written for either using hostlistener or maybe renderer2 way. But selecting radio button will apply some style or even maybe hover mechanism but as soon it will switch the radio other will take the style and exiting returned to original condition. I guess now you have to implement it. All the tools are there. Or maybe update your code snippet that you are trying or if you can product a stackblitz of it for anyone to view

Comment: I posted the solution to the orignal post. My approach wasn't working because triggering an on hover effect from code is illegal in javascript.